# GEOJSON to features (in ArcGIS) missing properties

Tags: python, json, arcgis

I have a GEOJSON file that I am using to create a feature class in ArcGIS. My JSON has some missing properties and I've noticed that ArcGIS's JSONToFeatures tool adds missing properties from adjacent objects.

For example, my raw json looks like this (note the second feature is missing the 'site_id' property):

```
     {"type": "Feature", "geometry": 
           {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-xxx.xxxx, xx.xxxxxxx],....]]]}, "properties": 
                {"id": "0", "address": "xx xxxxx", "site_id": "111111111"}},
     {"type": "Feature", "geometry": 
           {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-xxx.xxxx, xx.xxxxxxx],....]]]}, "properties": 
                {"id": "1", "address": "xx xxxxx"}},
```

Processing this json with the Arc JSONToFeatures tool produces a table that looks like this:

| OBJECTID | ID | Address | site_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | xx | xxx | 1111111 |
| 1 | xx | xxx | 1111111 |

NOTE: the site_id from the first record is added to the second record.

I'm using Python's requests and json modules to download and prepare the JSON file prior to creating the feature class. The JSON has 100,000 objects and this is a relatively regular process, not a one off task.

My question is: is there a way to prepare the JSON before transforming it to a feature class to avoid adding incorrect properties?  Or, is there a way to ask Arc to behave itself with these missing properties?

Comment: look for the site_id key and if not present add something like "site_id": ""  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using the JSON module's setdefault function.

```
url_ = r"https://...."
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
    for items in data['features']:
        if 'ID' not in items['properties']:
            del items
        else:
            items['properties'].setdefault("site_id", '000000000')
with open(r'F:\JSON.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```